# mislocated google-maps overlay

Tags: javascript, google-maps, overlay, image-registration

Although I have successfully deployed the Google Maps API, a new, larger area image is misplaced.

To demonstrate the issue, I have taken the code from the example
[***here***](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple) and changed the API key, the corner and centre lat-longs and the image ONLY.

You can see the result at [***this link***](http://rasp.inn.leedsmet.ac.uk/JUNK/junk.html)

It is evident in the NW corner that the overlay should be moved north, so that the black lines overlay the coastline.

Similarly at the SE corner, the overlay should be expanded? / moved? south so that the black line at the right edge of the image overlays the lake near Czechowice-Dziedzice (it may be necessary to zoom in to find this).

The image was produced by NCL. The input data has been examined using "panoply" and "ncdump"

The corner information from all 3 utilities agrees exactly.

Previous usage of the API has exhibited absolutely no problems and registration is exact.

---

Suggestions?

Regards

Paul Scorer

Comment: Have you tried cropping the image (topo12.body.png) to the "black border" in the image? Seems the coordinates you specify would align with the cropped image

Comment: your image is 1600 x 1600 ... cropped to the black border in the image it's about 1600 x 1014 ... and using that cropped image, it aligns almost perfectly (I wasn't too accurate in my crop though)

Comment: SOLVED: Image had extra transparent data. As you note, it needed to be cropped. Finger trouble :-(  Many thanks for the input though

Comment: PS: If you use "convert -trim ..." it does the job precisely!!